# 2D Soccer Goal Net

Tags: ios, spritekit

I want to make a 2D soccer game on iOS, I started with SpriteKit and got the ball physics working. 
Now, I could make the goal simple and static, but I'd love to make it make it elastic like a real one when the ball hits the net. 
I started creating the goal with the post, two ropes (on the top and rear side).
The ropes are basically like the ones in https://github.com/DigitalBuckeye/SKSwiftRopeDemo.

My problem is, when I hit the ball fast enough against the ropes, it will pass through them (even with usesPreciseCollisionDetection enabled).

I couldn't find any 2D sample for a good goal net on the web, tried searching in the box2d and chipmunk communities.

I wonder if I'll have to use a 3D engine for that.

Comment: It's not connected with question, but it's a tip: You should add .DS_Store files to .gitignore.

Comment: Thanks Marqin, but that github repo is not mine ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is, when I hit the ball fast enough against the ropes, it will pass through them (even with usesPreciseCollisionDetection enabled).

This is probably because it's moving so fast that:

- Frame n: Ball is still in front of net, not colliding with net.
- Frame n+1: Ball is on the different side of net, not colliding with net.

This problem [has it's own question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18604/how-do-i-handle-collision-detection-so-fast-objects-are-not-allowed-to-pass-thro), so I'll just summarize possible options:

1. Limit ball speed.
2. Check in every frame if ball had passed trough net.
3. Do collision test in each frame ( before moving ball ) with some raycast to check if path in front of ball is clear ( no obstacles, eg. net ).
4. *"Create a minimal bounding box that contains [ball position in] Frame n and Frame n+1 and see if the goal intersects [with this box]"* - as suggested in comment by [Erno de Weerd](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/52246/erno-de-weerd)

Comment: Or create a minimal bounding box that contains Frame n and Frame n+1 and see if the goal intersects

Comment: That suggestion may be a broad phase check. A bounding box can be created where the ball in frame n is near the edge of the net, n+1 behind and left of the net. The bounding box will intersect, however the path of the ball just missed the goal in reality.

Comment: ^ Only when ball can move on a curve.

Comment: Well if you make the boundingbox rotate you're correct that it will always intersect. However in a 2D game boundingboxes are usually axis aligned. In that event you can draw a box that intersects without the path actually hitting the goal. If you are going to rotate the boundingbox you are better off doing a line intersection of the ball path with the goal rope, which is the easiest solution to the OP's question. You get the intersectionpoint as a result to keep the ball inside the goal and have the net react to the impact at the correct spot.